# Python Selenium Testing. How can I extract the Auto Suggestions from search box on Google Home Page?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autocomplete, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing some auto testing Python + Selenium.Is there any way to check suggestion box in google for example using selenium. Something like I would like to now that suggestion table is revealed when auto test put google in search bar.

[image: Here is an axample]

Comment: There is a div with class 'gstl_0 sbdd_a' which contains these suggestions as a series of li elements inside it. These li contain the text of each suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following code:

```
suggestions = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li[class='sbsb_c gsfs']")
for element in suggestions:
    print(element.text)
```

Iterate through all elements using for loop, and call *text* on WebElement.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *Auto Suggestions* from *Search Box* on *Google Home Page* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [visibility_of_all_elements_located](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located) as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
search_field = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search_field.send_keys("google")
searchText_google_suggestion = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//form[@action='/search' and @role='search']//ul[@role='listbox']//li//span")))
for item in searchText_google_suggestion :
    print(item.text)
```

Console Output :

```
google
google translate
google maps
google drive
google pixel 2
google earth
google news
google scholar
google play store
google photos
```

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [How to automate Google Home Page auto suggestion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612605/how-to-automate-google-home-page-auto-suggestion/53613491#53613491)